# How to validate form based on input type=text/radio/checkbox using jQuery Validation Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a multi step form with dynamically generated fields that I need to validate using jQuery, this is the [form](https://jsfiddle.net/u19aohrc/2/) . How I can achieve this ?

```
// next step
    $('.form-horizontal .btn-next').on('click', function() {
        $("#multiphase").validate();

        $('input[type="text"]').each(function(){
            $(this).rule('add', {
                required: true,
                messages:{
                    required: "This field is required"
                }
            })
        })

    });
```

Comment: Is the validation only about a field being required or not?

Comment: @ciscoheat  Yes the fields are only required to have at least one character.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can validate elements using `"name"` attribute. you can show below example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#pseudoForm").validate({
    onfocusout:true,
    rules:{
      first_name:"required",
      last_name:"required"
    }
  });
</script>
<!-- whatever -->
<div id="pseudoForm">
  <input type="text" name="first_name"/>
  <input type="text" name="last_name"/>
</div>
```

also you can see reference as this link [LINK](http://jqueryvalidation.org/reference/)

Comment: I can't use `"name"` attribute because all input fields are generated dynamically and I only know the type of the input. In the form can be `x` number of fields and `n` number of steps

Answer (score 0):

You should map the input fields to an object containing the rules for the validation plugin. I assume you're using this: http://jqueryvalidation.org/

Here's the general idea:

```
  var fields = {};
  $('form').find(':input').each(function() {
    fields[this.name] = "required";
  });

  $('form').validate({
    rules: fields
  });
```

Of course you have to configure the plugin a bit more, but this is how you will handle the dynamic fields at least. An alternative would be to generate the rules server-side.